# Android - google search api

Tags: android

I am trying to include a google search call within an android app that would allow me to change the user input and add google specific 'wrap arounds'. For the sake of simplicity: let's say that I get the app user to ask about a particular website... The app asks them to input the company name...the app then manipulates the string to query google search.....with options like "intitle:"name"-inurl:name......sorry if this is a newbie question but I really could not find this .....thanks in advance.